# How to Retrieve Method's Signature in Squeak

Tags: reflection, squeak

```
printThisMethodSig: aSomething
stack := thisContext stackOfSize: 2.
Transcript show: (stack at: 2); cr.
```

`stack at: 2` returns the method context of the current method. It is possible to retrieve the compiled method of the current method using `method` message. I want to be able to print the whole signature of the method, for example: `from:to:`.
I looked at both MethodContext and CompiledMethod classes but could not find out how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `selector` message to retrieve the name of a `CompiledMethod`.